# Webpack not including ProvidePlugins

Tags: node.js, d3.js, webpack, vue.js

I have a small trial web application that I'm working on that uses the vue webpack template (https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack). I'm pretty new to webpack so I was assuming that I could add in to plugins a `new webpack.ProvidePlugin` and it would be available globally but when I do a `npm run dev` I get the following error:

```
/var/www/public/leadsStatsDashboard/liveleadstats/src/components/Hello.vue
  18:17  error  'd3' is not defined  no-undef
```

Which sounds like to me that it can't find the d3 reference. I'm no sure if there's some configuration I skipped over or what but any help would be appreciated. Here is the source for my files

Webpack.dev.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      d3: 'd3',
      crossfilter: 'crossfilter',
      dc: 'dc'
    })
  ],
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: config.build.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
      'd3': path.resolve(__dirname, '../bower_components/d3/d3.min.js'),
      'crossfilter': path.resolve(__dirname, '../bower_components/crossfilter/crossfilter.min.js'),
      'dc': path.resolve(__dirname, '../bower_components/dcjs/dc.js')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'vue-html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders()
  }
}
```

Hello.vue

```
<template>
<div id="pieChartContainer">
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
           return {
           // note: changing this line won't causes changes
           // with hot-reload because the reloaded component
           // preserves its current state and we are modifying
           // its initial state.
           msg: 'Hello World! This is a test'
        }
     },
     ready () {
     console.log(d3.version)
     }
  }
 </script>

 <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
 <style scoped>
   h1 {
    color: #42b983;
   }
 </style>
```

Comment: Don't you have to require d3 from your NPM install.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error isn't emitted from webpack, but from [eslint](http://eslint.org/).
I think the webpack part works as it should, in fact!

`no-undef` complains that you are using the global `d3` without importing or defining it somewhere.

The good news is, that's easy to fix. Use any of the following three possibilities:

- Just add the following block to your `.eslintrc.js`:

  ```
  "globals": {
    "d3": true
  }
  ```
- ...or use eslint comments within the file that requires `d3` implicitly (but that doesn't make much sense as you made it available globally and you would need to do this in every file you wish to use the global var):

  ```
  /* eslint-disable no-undef */
  ```
- ...or you could relax the eslint rule in your `.eslintrc.js` config:

  ```
  'rules': {
      // all other rules...
      'no-undef': 0
  }
  ```

Additional links:

- [Direct link to the template's eslintrc file](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/.eslintrc.js)
- [The eslint 'standard' file the template extends](https://github.com/feross/eslint-config-standard/blob/master/eslintrc.json)
- [Further reading on eslint's `no-undef` rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm new to the whole webpack and eslint ideas so you've been super helpful.