# vue cli 3 - ProvidePlugin doesn't work (vue.config.js)

Tags: webpack-4, vue-cli-3

I am trying to add `webpack.ProvidePlugin` which isn't working on `Vue-cli 3`.
I also tried to set `lodash` as a global import (so I won't have to import it in each store module).

vue.config

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ _: "lodash" })]
  }
};
```

build Error:

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: '_' is not defined (no-undef) at src/store/modules/templates.js:24:10:
  22 | export default Object.assign({}, base, {
  23 |   namespaced: true,
> 24 |   state: _.cloneDeep(initialState),
     |          ^
  25 |   mutations: {
  26 |     addTemplate(state, template) {
  27 |       if (!template) throw new Error("template is missing");
```

I built the project after adding the lines to `vue.config` and they gave me the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue doesn't seem to be with *Vue CLI* but with *eslint*. See this question for a similar issue (just replace `d3` with `_`): [Webpack not including ProvidePlugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077136/webpack-not-including-provideplugins)

In short, adding this to your *eslint* config (often found in `.eslintrc.js`) should make it work:

```
"globals": {
   "_": true
}
```